# Is it correct to see a different cabin value aside that passed in the get FlightOffers APi as travelerClass?

Tags: amadeus

From the documentation of the Get Route for the flight offers Api, I can add `travelerClass` as a filter to make a request. If I add say `travelerClass` as `ECONOMY`?
I expect to see only offers with `ECONOMY`. However I see that within the `fareDetailsBySegment` section in the `result`, I see that some Offers have their `cabin` values as other than `ECONOMY`. I see some with value of  `BUSINESS` while others as `PREMIUM_ECONOMY`.
Is this proper?

**My Concern**

- I want to be able to get all bookings that where ECONOMY based only. So I need to be sure that the flight offers returned in the first place are strictly limited by the `travelerClass`.

I will appreciate any clarity on the this issue. Also if there is a better way to go about this concern above, it will be most appreciated.

An example of my request is below:

```
Amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.get({
originLocationCode:      'SYD',
destinationLocationCode: 'BKK',
departureDate:           '2022-11-01',
adults:                  '1',
travelClass:             'ECONOMY'
}).then(...)
```

**Offer with BUSINESS instead of ECONOMY**

```
{
  "type": "flight-offer",
  "id": "22",
  "source": "GDS",
  "instantTicketingRequired": false,
  "nonHomogeneous": false,
  "oneWay": false,
  "lastTicketingDate": "2022-11-01",
  "numberOfBookableSeats": 6,
  "itineraries": [
    {
      "duration": "PT28H20M",
      "segments": [
        {
          "departure": {
            "iataCode": "SYD",
            "terminal": "1",
            "at": "2022-11-01T12:00:00"
          },
          "arrival": {
            "iataCode": "PVG",
            "terminal": "2",
            "at": "2022-11-01T19:30:00"
          },
          "carrierCode": "MU",
          "number": "562",
          "aircraft": {
            "code": "77W"
          },
          "operating": {
            "carrierCode": "MU"
          },
          "duration": "PT10H30M",
          "id": "13",
          "numberOfStops": 0,
          "blacklistedInEU": false
        },
        {
          "departure": {
            "iataCode": "PVG",
            "terminal": "1",
            "at": "2022-11-02T08:45:00"
          },
          "arrival": {
            "iataCode": "BKK",
            "at": "2022-11-02T12:20:00"
          },
          "carrierCode": "MU",
          "number": "541",
          "aircraft": {
            "code": "320"
          },
          "operating": {
            "carrierCode": "MU"
          },
          "duration": "PT4H35M",
          "id": "14",
          "numberOfStops": 0,
          "blacklistedInEU": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "price": {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "total": "4048.84",
    "base": "3858.00",
    "fees": [
      {
        "amount": "0.00",
        "type": "SUPPLIER"
      },
      {
        "amount": "0.00",
        "type": "TICKETING"
      }
    ],
    "grandTotal": "4048.84"
  },
  "pricingOptions": {
    "fareType": [
      "PUBLISHED"
    ],
    "includedCheckedBagsOnly": true
  },
  "validatingAirlineCodes": [
    "MU"
  ],
  "travelerPricings": [
    {
      "travelerId": "1",
      "fareOption": "STANDARD",
      "travelerType": "ADULT",
      "price": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "total": "4048.84",
        "base": "3858.00"
      },
      "fareDetailsBySegment": [
        {
          "segmentId": "13",
          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
          "fareBasis": "YSE0WDNQ",
          "class": "Y",
          "includedCheckedBags": {
            "quantity": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "segmentId": "14",
          "cabin": "BUSINESS",
          "fareBasis": "QSE0WCNL",
          "class": "Q",
          "includedCheckedBags": {
            "quantity": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to apply the filter for cabin class, I suggest you to try with `POST` method.

in `POST` method has more search criteria you can apply, below example is something that I have tried and it works: response only contains `ECONOMY` classes by updating values under `cabinRestrictions`.

details of the request model is available in [API reference page](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference)

```
 amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.post(JSON.stringify({
  "currencyCode": "USD",
  "originDestinations": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "originLocationCode": "SYD",
      "destinationLocationCode": "BKK",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2022-11-01"
      }
    }
  ],
  "travelers": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "travelerType": "ADULT"
    }
  ],
  "sources": [
    "GDS"
  ],
  "searchCriteria": {
    "maxFlightOffers": 10,
    "flightFilters": {
      "cabinRestrictions": [
        {
          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
          "coverage": "ALL_SEGMENTS",
          "originDestinationIds": [
            1
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})).then(...)
```